# Url query parameter with no value on ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, query-string

This is my controller's action for `POST api/foo?bar=true` requests:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/foo")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Update(bool bar)
{}
```

It works fine, but when I try to do the same with a query parameter with no value like `POST api/foo?bar`, the action above doesn't work and this message is returned:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'bar' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage]
>   Update(Boolean)' in
>   'Foo.Controllers.FooController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter.

How can I make requests like `POST api/foo?bar` get into the `Update()` action? Optional parameter/Other type for the parameter?

Any help is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Made the **parameter nullable** leaving the action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/foo")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Update(bool? bar)
{}
```